# Monogame - Problem with lighting 3d mesh

Tags: monogame, lighting, 3d-meshes

I am having an issue with lighting my 3d icosphere. For some reason,the lighting appears to be coming from the correct direction  (+X, -Y, -Z) but it also appears to be coming from (-X,+Y,+Z) and I have no idea why. I am not very well versed in 3D in Monogame yet, can anyone point me in the right direction of what is going on here?

[image: Shaded icosphere]
EDIT:

The code for the shader

```
VertexToPixel ColoredVS(float4 inPos : POSITION, float3 inNormal : NORMAL, float4 inColor : COLOR)
{
    VertexToPixel Output = (VertexToPixel)0;
    float4x4 preViewProjection = mul(View, Projection);
    float4x4 preWorldViewProjection = mul(World, preViewProjection);

    Output.Position = mul(inPos, preWorldViewProjection);
    Output.Color = inColor;

    float3 Normal = normalize(mul(normalize(inNormal), World));
    Output.LightingFactor = 1;
    if (xEnableLighting)
        Output.LightingFactor = dot(Normal, -xLightDirection);

    return Output;
}

PixelToFrame ColoredPS(VertexToPixel PSIn)
{
    PixelToFrame Output = (PixelToFrame)0;

    Output.Color = PSIn.Color;
    Output.Color.rgb *= saturate(PSIn.LightingFactor) + xAmbient;

    return Output;
}
```

And this is for calculating normals

```
            for (int i = 0; i < Vertices.Length; i++)
                Vertices[i].Normal = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < Indices.Length; i += 3)
            {
                Vector3 p1 = Vertices[Indices[i]].Position;
                Vector3 p2 = Vertices[Indices[i + 1]].Position;
                Vector3 p3 = Vertices[Indices[i + 2]].Position;

                Vector3 v1 = p2 - p1;
                Vector3 v2 = p3 - p1;
                Vector3 normal = Vector3.Cross(v1, v2);

                normal.Normalize();

                Vertices[Indices[i]].Normal += normal;
                Vertices[Indices[i + 1]].Normal += normal;
                Vertices[Indices[i + 2]].Normal += normal;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Vertices.Length; i++)
                Vertices[i].Normal.Normalize();
```

Comment: We can't say anything when you don't provide any code

Comment: @Bálint sure but what code in particular, the vertice creation? The normal creation? The lighting shader? All of it? I didn't want to include huge chunks of code without knowing which were important or not.

Comment: Probably the shader and the normal creation. Anything that takes part in deciding the amount of light on a part of a model

Comment: @Bálint Okay updated

Comment: Okay, first of all to test this, I'd set the color of a fragment to the normal to see if there's a problem with them. If the pixels on opposite sides get the same color, then it's a problem with them. A possible error could be, that you multiply the normal by World to rotate it, but World contains the translation too, in which case you need to multiply the normal by the upper left 3x3 chunk of the World matrix instead

Comment: @Bálint I'm not sure I understand "Set the color of a fragment to the normal". And how would I multiply it by the 3x3 instead of the full matrix?

Comment: 1.) The normal is a 3d vector, the color is a 3d of the fragment (pixel) is a3d color. Set the color to the normal. 2.) I'm not an hlsl expert, but there's surely a way to get the upper left 3x3 part of a 4x4 matrix

Comment: @Bálint so it does appear that my normal calculation is the culprit but I am not too sure why. The colours on opposite sides are the same value.

Comment: @Bálint Figured it out, I am a dummy and had "CullMode = None" so some of my vertices for this object were clockwise instead of counterclockwise so thats where that came from

Comment: add an answer to this question and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being caused by the fact that I had CullMode set to None in my RasterState and so I couldn't immediately tell that my triangles were facing the wrong direction. Because triangles were being rendered I thought that they were all correctly ordered in counter-clockwise order when they were in fact not. I changed CullMode back to its original value and fixed the ordering of the vertices in my vertex array and that fixed the shading.